# polymer core-list inside angular md-tabs

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I am really new in web developing. I am trying to display a core-list from polymer project inside angular material tabs.

```
   <md-tabs md-border-bottom>
        <md-tab label="Tab1">

          <template is="auto-binding" id="page-template">
            <div class="content" flex>
              <core-list data="{{data}}" flex>
                <template>
                  <div class="row">
                    List row: {{index}}, User data from model: {{model.name}}
                  </div>
                </template>
              </core-list>
            </div>
          </template>

        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Tab2">
          <md-content class="md-padding">
            <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur
              felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam placerat, tortor in ultrices porttitor, orci enim rutrum enim, vel tempor sapien arcu a tellus. Vivamus convallis sodales ante varius gravida. Curabitur a purus vel augue ultrices
              ultricies id a nisl. Nullam malesuada consequat diam, a facilisis tortor volutpat et. Sed urna dolor, aliquet vitae posuere vulputate, euismod ac lorem. Sed felis risus, pulvinar at interdum quis, vehicula sed odio. Phasellus in enim venenatis,
              iaculis tortor eu, bibendum ante. Donec ac tellus dictum neque volutpat blandit. Praesent efficitur faucibus risus, ac auctor purus porttitor vitae. Phasellus ornare dui nec orci posuere, nec luctus mauris semper.</p>
            <p>Morbi viverra, ante vel aliquet tincidunt, leo dolor pharetra quam, at semper massa orci nec magna. Donec posuere nec sapien sed laoreet. Etiam cursus nunc in condimentum facilisis. Etiam in tempor tortor. Vivamus faucibus egestas enim, at
              convallis diam pulvinar vel. Cras ac orci eget nisi maximus cursus. Nunc urna libero, viverra sit amet nisl at, hendrerit tempor turpis. Maecenas facilisis convallis mi vel tempor. Nullam vitae nunc leo. Cras sed nisl consectetur, rhoncus
              sapien sit amet, tempus sapien.</p>
            <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante
              eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
          </md-content>
        </md-tab>

      </md-tabs>
```

My code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJjLNM
The core-list won't render.
I think there is a problem with absolute position of the angular's tab, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30412757/edit) your question and provide some more details: What exactly do you expect your code to do? And what is not working as expected?

Comment: Sorry, i probably pasted wrong code. I am expecting to see core-list inside tab, but when I paste it in the tab it wont render. The tab has absolute position, do you think that this is the problem? Thanks.